# WP Nonce as URL param after successful login

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

Context:
*A simple Vanilla JS SPA wrapped in and served via WP, as a custom WP template (the template page only contain custom code, without any WP headers, etc.).*

Purpose
Even if the user is already authenticated in WP itself to be able to load the JS app, to make Ajax calls to the wp-api we need **to also pass the nonce as auth header**.

Usually the nonce is provided by using an inline script, and print the nonce with PHP, this way:

```
wp_add_inline_script( 
    'script-handle',
    'const my_script_params = ' . json_encode( 
            array(
                'ajax_url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                'my_nonce'   => wp_create_nonce( 'my_nonce' )
            )       
    ),
    'before' 
);
```

However I would like to avoid this approach, mainly because I do not load any WP headers and therefore the scripts enquque doe snot work.

Therefore my solution is **to pass back the nonce in the U**RL after a successful login:

```
function redirect_with_nonce(){
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest');
    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'nonce', $nonce, get_option('siteurl'));
    wp_redirect($redirect_url);
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_login', 'redirect_with_nonce', 10, 2);
```

and finally **take it from the URL and save it to the localStorage** with a few lines of JS like:

```
function refreshNonce() {
  var query_string = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  var nonce = query_string.get("nonce") || null;

  if (nonce) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("nonce", nonce);
  }

}
```

I was wondering if this approach can be recomended, if this is better than the "inline script" usual approach and/or more or less secure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If WordPress nonces were actually Numbers Used Once, this would be fine. But these nonces have a longer lifetime than that. They aren't invalidated when used by WordPress.

So it is a **security risk** to embed them in URLs (that is, in GET requests). GET request URLs can be logged by proxy servers and are visible in transit even when https is in use.

So don't do this.

Information carried in the body of the HTML document you send out is, when you use https, not visible in transit. It's encrypted. The end user, the browser user, can see it of course, but not third parties like proxy servers.

Comment: That make sense, indeed, thanks for your quick feedback. But if the alternative is just printing it as plain javascript i nthe html head tag, isn't it the same level of insecurity? The html document is anyaway also part of the response sent to the client, right?

Anyway, and overall, do you have any other reccomendations? Since I cannot print it using the usual method because I avoid WP head, and since my URL idea is not secure, what else could I use? Perhaps I can send it as a cookie with PHP after the login?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Then maybe with setcookie() I can send the nonce value to a cookie under SSL...should be quite secure right?

Comment: Yes cookies are secure. But if you need to see the cookie value from browser Javascript don't set the cookie's httpOnly flag.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, I've set the cookis to be SSL but not http only of course, seems to be a robut solution, personally even better than printing some javascript with PHP. However, even if now the nonce generation and retrieval is solved, the problem is that I get error 403 (error with cookie and nonce)...need to figure out why...

Comment: Ok I found a solution to the last issue, and answered myself here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77322178/wp-nonce-rest-cookie-invalid-nonce/77322457#77322457 thanks a lot for your support @O.Jones!